How to wait async tasks in java mockmvc tests?
We have a system that we send notification asynchronously to users under certain conditions. We also keep the notifications in a DB repository.
We want to write a test to ensure that if the notification conditions are not satisfied, notification is not sent. In that case no entry is written to DB (notifications repository).
As an ad-hoc solution we check the Notification Repository to see whether the notification is sent or not. However, a notification might have been sent even if it is not present in the repository at the time we check since sending notification happens asynchronously.
Is there a proper way to wait all async tasks are completed before checking Notif. Repository?
Note: We handle the converse (notifications should be send) rather easily with awaitility by checking the notif. repo. every 100 ms until the notification has reached timeout of 60 seconds reached.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
